# Is $f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \sqrt{x} e^{-n^2 x}$ continuous?. Where is bluff?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

I have a function defined by $f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \sqrt{x} e^{-n^2 x}$. The task is to check, whether $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$. I have proposition of a solution and I would like someone to point out a bluff as there most likely is one - solution is suspisciously too short. 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sqrt(x) \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} e^{-n^2x} = \sqrt(x) A_{n}
\end{equation}
I do it because x doesn't change when summing, I treat it as constant. The sum $A_{n}$ is obviously convergent, so there exist some finite M conforming $A_{n}$ < M. Thus, I can write $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) < lim_{x \rightarrow 0} xM = 0$
well. that would be finished, but as I have mentioned before, I suspect bluff.

Comment: zero, of course, I'll correct it atm

Comment: The sum is so obviously convergent that it is not... What if $x = 0$ ?

Comment: x is constant, so I can write $ (\frac{1}{e^x})^n^2 < (\frac{1}{e^x})^n $. Right side is convergent as geometric sequence. @D.Thomine

Comment: @user3132736 But geometric sequence is convergent for $|q|<1$, whether $e^0=1$.

Comment: Isn't f(0) = 0?

Comment: @user3132736 you have not necessarily proved that

Comment: Although you represent the sum as $A_n$, it is not a function of $n$ but of $x$.  $n$ is a dummy variable.  It would be better to represent it as $A(x)$

Comment: @Addison , where is the mistake, then?

Comment: Saying that $A_n < M$

Comment: In your post, you said "the sum $A_n$ is obviously convergent". It is not. Hence, the conclusion (that $A_n$ is bounded) does not hold. The multiplication by $\sqrt{x}$ does not magically fix this.

Comment: @user3132736 The $M$ depends on $x$. You have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\cdot M(x)$, where $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}M(x) = \infty$, hence you have the indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$.

Comment: okay, thank you all, it was quite an obvious mistake on my part. I was checking it for smaller and smaller values of x in Mathematica, which returned convergence, which wasn't smartest of ideas in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary approach to obtain the desired limit.

**As $x$ tends to $0^+$**, we have

> $$\sqrt{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{\large -xn^2} \longrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}. \tag{*}$$

*Proof.*
Let $x>0$ and $n\geq 0$. Since $\displaystyle t \in [0,+\infty) \rightarrow e^{\large -xt^2}$ is a decreasing function, we have 
$$
e^{-x(n+1)^2} \leq e^{-xt^2} \leq e^{-xn^2}, \quad t \in [n,n+1], \tag1
$$ integrating $(1)$ **with respect to $t$**, we get
$$
\int_n^{n+1}e^{-xt^2}dt \leq \int_n^{n+1}e^{\large -x n^2}dt = e^{\large -x n^2}\tag2
$$ and
$$
\int_{n-1}^{n}e^{\large -x n^2}dt = e^{\large -x n^2}\leq \int_{n-1}^{n}e^{-xt^2} dt. \tag3
$$
Then, summing $(2)$ for $n\geq0$, gives
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xt^2}dt \leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{\large -x n^2} \tag4
$$
and summing $(3)$ for $n\geq 1$, gives
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{\large -x n^2} \leq \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xt^2}dt. \tag5
$$Recalling the [gaussian integral evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), we have
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xt^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, \quad x>0.\tag6
$$ Hence, combining $(4)$, $(5)$ and $(6)$, gives
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{\large -x n^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \tag7
$$
leading, as $x$ tends to $0^+$, to the announced result $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you, you did more than I asked for. :)

Comment: @user3132736 You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Note the summation when $x=0$ is infinite since it is an infinite sum of 1's, thus contradicting your argument of finite $M$.

Comment: It is 0 times sequence of 1's.

Comment: Zero times infinity is an indeterminant form and does not necessarily imply $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: It isn't something approaching 0 times something approaching infinity. It is definite zero times something.

Comment: @user3132736 No, an infinite sum of 1's is infinite. When $x=0$ you have an indeterminant form.

Comment: @user3132736 Look at both components. When $x=0$, the square root is $0$. Now consider the sum: it is $1+1+1+1+...$ going off into infinity.